# Django Page not found (404) error with url config

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a problem with urls config in my Django project, in my root url config i have this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^$', include('main.urls')),
                   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   url(r'^profile/', include('accounts.urls')),
                   ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

And in my app url config i have this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^$', 'main.view.home', name='main_home'),
                   url(r'^integrations/$', 'main.view.integrations', name='main_integrations'),
)
```

But when I go to render this **url http://127.0.0.1:8000/integrations/** I obtain an error 404 Not Found.

Thanks by yours answers.

Comment: whats the name of your app? main? can show the view code?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, my app named 'main' and this is my view code:

```
def home(request):
user = request.user
if not user.is_authenticated():
    data = {
        'messages': get_messages(request),
    }

    return render_to_response('home.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

data = {
    'messages': get_messages(request),
}
return render_to_response('home_user.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def integrations(request):
    return render_to_response('/main/integrations.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```